# How can I make sure I have a ground wire connection for my range?

Tags: electrical, grounding, neutral

I recently replaced my electric range. While doing so I notice that the previous range had neutral and ground bridged, even though it had a 4-wire cord. I'm now a little bit insecure about what to do, because the reason may be there is not a real ground wire and the previous person who replaced it was aware.

How can I make sure I have a real ground wire connection? Should I just install the new range the way it supposed to be with a 4-wire hook-up? Thanks in advance.

Comment: You say, "the previous range had neutral and ground bridged". Was it bridged at the receptacle? In other words, was it 4 wires leading to a three prong receptacle with a 3 wire cable leading to the oven/range?

Comment: @AdamO "even though it had a 4-wire cord"

Answer (score 9, accepted):

First of all, I prefer hardwired connections. It avoids a lot of the issues. But if, for whatever reason, you want to stay with cord/plug/receptacle:

- Turn off the breaker.
- Open up the receptacle.
- See what wires you actually have. If you are not sure what you're looking at, upload a picture.

What you should see on a proper 4-wire receptacle is one of:

- A 4-wire cable with black/red/white/green
- A 4-wire cable with black/red/white/bare
- 4 individual wires, 2 of black or red or blue or yellow or... (but not white, green, bare), 1 white, 1 green or bare
- 3 individual wires, 2 of black or red or blue or yellow or... (but not white, green, bare) with metal box and metal conduit.

Anything else and you have a problem.

You also need to consider *wire size*. In particular, a 40A or 50A circuit will use the exact same receptacle but the wire size requirements are different. Compare with [an ampacity table](https://www.cerrowire.com/products/resources/tables-calculators/ampacity-charts/), 60 C column for typical copper cable, 75 C for everything else. If you are not sure, upload pictures and ask for help.

Assuming that you indeed have 4 wires (or 3 + metal conduit ground) then your receptacle is fine and the new range should be installed *without* the neutral/ground bond. Actually, there is never a time where you would install a 4-wire plug *with* a neutral/ground bond. There are certain situations where you might be able to (and safe to) install a 4-wire plug/cored/receptacle, without the neutral/ground bond and without an actual ground wire. But that gets complicated and is of limited applicability.

Comment: [Surely this is a duplicate, no?](https://www.google.com/search?q=site%3Adiy.stackexchange.com+oven+ground+connection&rlz=1C1GCEU_enUS1019US1019)

Comment: @isherwood Feel free to pick what you feel is an appropriate duplicate and VTC. And if it is close enough, I'll VTC too.